# node.js + express + secureConnection event in https

Tags: node.js, https, express, ssl

I am a beginner in node.js. Here is what I am trying to do using express + https.
- node.js https server on port 443 
- C client connects to sever
- Mobile client connects to server and does GET
- node.js server sends GET request to C client and sends response back to mobile device

While sending GET request from node.js to C client, I could not get hold of TLS socket instance.

The node.js https documentation says

```
Class: https.Server# 

This class is a subclass of tls.Server and emits events same as http.Server. See
http.Server for more information.
```

after storing socket

```
https.on('connection', function(socket) {
global_https_obj[0]=socket;
});
```

and doing `global_https_obj[0].write("DEADBEEF")` .. it sends plain text traffic without SSL header and client blocks on `SSL_read() [openSSL]`[ C client does receives GET request but openSSL gives decryption alert and fails to decrypt it ]

It seems TLS socket is accessible through `secureConnection` event and is not emitted by https.

guys is there any way get hold of TLS socket? or is it possible to add secureConnection event listener in https?

Comment: my bad .. had both connection and secureConnection listener.. removed connection listener and is working.